# Most OpenTelemetry instrumentations are disabled in my Spring application

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, open-telemetry, kubernetes-operator

I have injected an OpenTelemetry JAVA agent in a Spring application in OpenShift via kubernetes operator, but most instrumentations are disabled and not generating traces.

OpenTelemetry Agent image: ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-java:1.28.0

JAVA version: openjdk 11.0.15

Kubernetes version: v1.25.10+3fe2906

After setting OTEL_JAVAAGENT_DEBUG to true, I see most instrumentations are disabled:

```
...
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:36:50:133 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.instrumentation.InstrumentationLoader - Loading instrumentation executors [class io.opentelemetry.javaagent.instrumentation.executors.ExecutorsInstrumentationModule]
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:36:50:133 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.instrumentation.InstrumentationModule - Instrumentation executors is disabled
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:36:50:133 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.instrumentation.InstrumentationLoader - Loading instrumentation internal-application-logging [class io.opentelemetry.javaagent.instrumentation.internal.logging.ApplicationLoggingInstrumentationModule]
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:36:50:133 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.instrumentation.InstrumentationModule - Instrumentation internal-application-logging is disabled
...
```

Lettuce instrumentation works as intended, generating traces which show up in our OpenTelemetry collector:

```
...
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:36:50:838 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.instrumentation.InstrumentationLoader - Loading instrumentation lettuce [class io.opentelemetry.javaagent.instrumentation.lettuce.v4_0.LettuceInstrumentationModule]
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:36:50:842 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.instrumentation.InstrumentationLoader - Loading instrumentation lettuce [class io.opentelemetry.javaagent.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_0.LettuceInstrumentationModule]
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:36:50:908 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.instrumentation.InstrumentationLoader - Loading instrumentation lettuce [class io.opentelemetry.javaagent.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.LettuceInstrumentationModule]
...
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:37:07:128 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.instrumentation.InstrumentationModule - Applying instrumentation: lettuce [class io.opentelemetry.javaagent.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.LettuceInstrumentationModule] on org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@64db4967
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:37:07:128 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.HelperInjector - Injecting classes onto class loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@64db4967 -> [io.opentelemetry.javaagent.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.TracingHolder, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.LettuceTelemetry, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.OpenTelemetryTracing, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.LettuceTelemetryBuilder, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.OpenTelemetryTracing$1, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.LettuceNetAttributesGetter, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.OpenTelemetryTracing$OpenTelemetryEndpoint, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.OpenTelemetryTracing$OpenTelemetryTraceContextProvider, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.OpenTelemetryTracing$OpenTelemetryTracerProvider, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.OpenTelemetryTracing$OpenTelemetryTracer, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.OpenTelemetryTracing$OpenTelemetryTraceContext, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.v5_1.OpenTelemetryTracing$OpenTelemetrySpan, io.lettuce.core.protocol.OtelCommandArgsUtil, io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.lettuce.common.LettuceArgSplitter]
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:37:07:128 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.HelperInjector - Injecting classes onto class loader <bootstrap> -> [io.opentelemetry.javaagent.bootstrap.field.VirtualFieldAccessor$io$lettuce$core$protocol$AsyncCommand$io$opentelemetry$javaagent$shaded$io$opentelemetry$context$Context]
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:37:07:129 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.HelperInjector - Injecting classes onto class loader <bootstrap> -> [io.opentelemetry.javaagent.bootstrap.field.VirtualFieldImpl$io$lettuce$core$protocol$AsyncCommand$io$opentelemetry$javaagent$shaded$io$opentelemetry$context$Context]
[otel.javaagent 2023-07-26 11:37:07:132 -0300] [main] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.AgentInstaller$TransformLoggingListener - Transformed io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources -- org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@64db4967
...
```

I have tried setting both default and individual instrumentation flags to 'true':

```
OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_COMMON_DEFAULT_ENABLED=true
OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_TOMCAT_ENABLED=true
```

But nothing changed. Most instrumentations were still disabled with only a couple working properly.

Just to be sure, I tried disabling lettuce instrumentation:

```
OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_LETTUCE_ENABLED=false
```

And it worked. It showed as disabled and stopped generating traces, so I don't think it has to do with enabling/disabling instrumentations.
Moreover, we have working java instrumentation agents on both Azure and AWS kubernetes, which leads me to believe it has something to do with our OpenShift cluster.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: any chance you're running dynatrace in that environment? your issue reminds me of https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/5885

Comment: Yes, we have a dynatrace agent in the environment.
I guess that's what's going on then.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The OneAgent does not disable any opentelemetry-modules. The spans exported by the OpenTelemetry agent will look exactly like the OneAgent isn't present at all. The OneAgent just won't integrate spans from certain otel-agent-modules into its own distributed traces structure.

So, we don't suppress the OTel Java agent from creating all the spans it needs to and then sending them to whatever exporters are configured. That will work and we don't touch the spans generated/created.

Which means that in e.g. Jaeger, you will see all the spans as if the OneAgent was not present.

However, if you have the Dynatrace OTel code module integration enabled, the spans that the OA ingests via the code module (NOT by the OTel exporter) will be missing certain instrumentation libraries that we know the OA is already instrumenting well - such as HTTP).

So, we do suppress some spans, but this will only be visible inside Dynatrace, when we use the code module ingestion. Whatever exporter you have configured on the OTel Java agent is unaffected by this.

This is basically to avoid double tracing and a lot of duplicated spans in your Distributed Trace view.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution to the discussion. Some people in my company also said something similar to what you are stating so I guess I'll keep looking.

Comment: @FelipeKT are you missing spans from any instrumentation libraries when using OTel agent and OneAgent?

Comment: Apparently something is disabling OTel instrumentations, making it generate only lettuce related traces.
I'm not aware of any behavior changes on the OneAgent/Dynatrace side of things, but I was unable to check.
Will do it asap.

Comment: @FelipeKT are you sending traces to somewhere else other than Dynatrace? If yes, could you maybe share the results of your trace with and without the OneAgent?

Comment: Technically speaking, our PoC doesn't involve Dynatrace.
It consists of using OTel auto instrumentation to send traces and logs to an OTel collector-contrib with an Elasticsearch exporter configured.
We just happen to have OneAgent running in our environment.
We've tested again setting OneAgent pods to 0, but the result was still the same.

Comment: As part of our PoC, we managed to successfully inject auto instrumentation in an application running on Kubernetes in our cloud environment.
It's generating traces as expected and our platform team has confirmed the presence of OneAgent in the cluster just like in our OpenShift environment.
If we needed more proof that OneAgent isn't responsible for what is happening, I guess this is it.

Comment: Happy to hear that.
I'd suggest opening an issue in the otel-java-instrumentation repo. They may have further troubleshoot steps. Also Dynatrace support is there to help if you suspect OA is the culprit.